# Change html element after jquery.ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to change the HTML element `#result` after my code is sent via the post method

I tried to use `.html()` / `.replace()` but they did not work.

Here is my code

JS:

```
$("form input[type=submit]").click(function() {
  var your_selected_value = $('#bkb').val();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'getpro.php',
    data: {
      "selected": your_selected_value
    },

    success: function(data) {
      $('#result').html(data);


    },
    error: function(data) {

    }
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="lnw2">
  <form method="post" action='#'>
    <select id="bkb" name="selectpro">
      <?php loadcountry(); ?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Get Selected Values" />
  </form>
</div>
<div id="result">
  <h3>test</h3>
</div>
```

PHP:

```
<? php
if (isset($_POST['selected'])) {
  $selected_val = $_POST['selected']; // Storing Selected Value In Variable
  echo "answer " .$selected_val; // Displaying Selected Value
}
?>
```

Comment: `<?php
    if(isset($_POST['selected'])){
    $selected_val = $_POST['selected'];  // Storing Selected Value In Variable
    echo "answer  " .$selected_val;  // Displaying Selected Value
    }
    ?>`

Comment: please put that info in your question by clicking the "edit" button

Comment: `<div id="lnw2">
        <form method="post" action='#'>
            <select id="bkb" name="selectpro">
                <?php  
        loadcountry();
        ?>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Get Selected Values" />
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="result">
        <h3>test</h3>
    </div>`

Comment: You're not preventing your `form` from being submitted in the first place, use [`preventDefault()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) method. Also what does `loadcountry()` method do?

Comment: Try debugging it by adding `console.log(data)` inside success to see if it at least returns a success value.

Comment: To prevent submit form, just change input type from submit to button. Now your ajax call will display result which you code in success method.

Comment: loadcountry() is load array to dropdown lis

` function loadcountry(){
        $selectinterest = array(' '=>" ",'Bangkok'=>"กรงเทพเมืองดี",'Chonburi' =>"ฉลามชล",'Burirum'=>"เนวิน");
        foreach( $selectinterest as $key => $option ) {
    echo '<option value="'.$option.'">'.$key.'</option>';
    }
`

Comment: oh after i append 
event.preventDefault(); it works !
but i see another forum ,i haven't seen this code before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, you're not preventing your `form` from being submitted in the first place, use `preventDefault()` method.

Here's the reference:

- https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

So your jQuery should be like this:

```
$("form input[type=submit]").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var your_selected_value = $('#bkb').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'getpro.php',
        data: {
            "selected": your_selected_value
        },

        success: function(data) {
            $('#result').html(data);


        },
        error: function(data) {

        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Get Selected Values" />
```

with

```
<input type="button" name="submit" value="Get Selected Values" />
```